# How can I alternate the page numbering for the front and back pages?

Tags: page-numbering

In the ABNT rules for writing an article, the page numbering has to be like shown here:

[image]

(top of the page and on the right for front page and left for back page; ignore number size, it is already set in my model).

Problem is, I can't seem to get latex to do that. I'd be happy if you guys could help me.

My actual page numbering settings for the document is:

```
% Elementos pré-textuais

\renewcommand{\pretextual}{%
    \pagenumbering{gobble} % Sem números nas páginas antes do texto %Caso queira inserir números romanos, utilizar \pagenumbering{roman}
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
    \aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
}

\newcommand\pagenumberingignorereset[1]{\gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname\c@page}} %Comando para não ignorar as páginas anteriores

% Configura layout para elementos textuais
\renewcommand{\textual}{%
    \pagenumberingignorereset{arabic} % A numeração das páginas é em algarismos arábicos, contando as páginas anteriores (Para iniciar em 1, utilizar 
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \pagestyle{abntheadings}
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{abntchapfirst}
   %\nouppercaseheads
    \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
}

% Configura layout para elementos pós-textuais
\renewcommand{\postextual}{%
    \chapterstyle{abnt}
    \phantompart
}
```

Thanks for the help!

> Remark by user Dr. Manuel Kuhener: "ABNT" is short for "Associação
>   Brasileira de Normas Técnicas" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_National_Standards_Organization)).

Comment: Look at [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package.

Comment: What journal on earth uses `abnt` + Latex for submissions?

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

```
\documentclass[article,twoside]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}

\renewcommand{\textual}{\pagestyle{myheadings}}


\begin{document}

\textual 

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Be aware that **there is nothing in the rules stating what you say they do**. Check the rules out [here](http://posticsenasp.ufsc.br/files/2014/04/abntnbr6022.pdf). There is no specification of page numbering or margins, for that matter. It would be much better to use a standard class, or a class provided by the journal you're submitting to.

Comment: +1 for the "Be aware" :)